# Sending row/cell data on click to the function - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am retrieving table data from componentWillMount and showing it as UI. I want to trigger a fuction when the row/cell is clicked and return that value back to another PHP so that i can query the backend using that retrieved cell value.

- index = 0,1,2,3 ( I have 4 columns )
- row = data for each index.

I am not sure why this.state.testTime is not sending the correct value to handleClick function. Does anyone have any inputs on this? Thanks.

```
 _handleClick: function (event) {
        this.setState({testTime: event.target.value});
        console.log(event.target.value);    
        var data = {
            testTime: this.state.testTime
        }

        console.log("clicked");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "http://localhost:8080/TEST/capture.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error:function(data)
            {
                alert("Data sending failed");
            }
        });
    },

return (
<tbody>
 {tableData.map((row, index) => {
       return (
              <tr key={"row_" + index} >
                {row.map((cell, index) => {
                    return (
                        <td key={"cell_" + index} onClick={this._handleClick} value={this.state.testTime} >{cell}</td>
                         );
                 })}
              </tr>
             );
  })}
</tbody>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate) is an async function and it accepts a callback as the second argument that will be executed once `setState` is completed and the component is re-rendered. So you either need to use `event.target.value` directly for the `data` variable or put your code into the callback:

```
this.setState({testTime: event.target.value} ,() => {
   var data = {testTime: this.state.testTime}
   ...
   $.ajax...
});
```